# Difference between Java and Kotlin generic methods

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

Obtained analogues syntax constructs for generic methods in Java and Kotlin:

```
public <T> void method() {}
fun <T> method() {}

public <T> T method(T... p) { return p[0]; }
fun <T> method(vararg p: T): T? { return p[0] }

public <T extends ClassA> T method(T[] p) { ... }
fun <T : ClassA> method(p: Array<T>): T { ... }

public <T extends ClassA & InterfaceA> T method(T[] p) {}
fun <T : ClassA> method(p: Array<T>): T where T : InterfaceA {}

public void method(Collection<? extends ClassA> collection) {}
fun method(collection: Collection<out ClassA>) {}

public void method(Collection<? super ClassA> collection) {}
fun method(collection: Collection<in ClassA>) {}

public void method(Collection<?> collection) {} 
fun method(collection: Collection<*>) {}
```

Are there any other additional differences (syntactically or conceptual) for generalized methods in Java and Kotlin? Or innovations for generic methods in Kotlin? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is still something going on with `@JvmSuppressWildcards`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Exactly, thank you! Annotations JvmSuppressWildcards and JvmWildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In generic code, ‘?’ represents an unknown type. It is known as the wildcard. There are several uses of a wildcard, including as the type of a field, local variable, or parameter.
>   While Java’s type system offers wildcard types, Kotlin doesn’t. However, it has two different things; declaration-site variance and type projections as an alternative to wildcard types.

taken from [Kotlin vs Java: Most Important Differences That You Must Know](https://hackr.io/blog/kotlin-vs-java)